# View containing paging and Multiple Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page that display list of Categories and also have a search box to search categories. The list of categories uses paging.

### View Contains following Code:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MvcWebsite.Models.User.ListOfCategories>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

foreach (var item in Model)
{
....
}
```

### Model contains following code:

```
namespace MvcWebsite.Models.User
{    
    public class ListOfCategories

    {
        public int lngCatId { get; set; }
        public Byte intStatus { get; set; }
        public string txtTitle { get; set; }

        public ListOfCategories()
        {
            intStatus = 1;
        }
    }

    public class SearchBox
    {
        public string txtSearch { get; set; }
    }


public class UserViewModel
{
    public ListOfCategories ListOfCategories { get; set; }
    public SearchBox SearchBox { get; set; }
}
}
```

In my view if I change MvcWebsite.Models.User.CategoriesList to MvcWebsite.Models.User.UserViewModel I get error.

What do I need to do so paging and search box both work in page?

Answer (score 0):

There a few problems with your code even with your preliminary version (with `ListOfCategories` used as a view model).

1. You try to iterate through `ListOfCategories` whereas this class does not implement `IEnumerable` interface
2. You use a naming convention `ListOfCategories`, but in fact you class represents a single `Category`.
3. You want to change the view model to `MvcWebsite.Models.User.UserViewModel` but you do not change your view code.
4. You use inappropriate naming conventions (please read the [Clean Code book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882))
5. You should not represent your `Status` by byte, it is better to use enum type to make it readable.

All in all your code should probably look like this:

```
public enum StatusType
{
    BasicStatus = 1,
    OtherStatus = 2,
    YetAnotherStatus = 3
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public StatusType Status { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        Status = StatusType.BasicStatus;
    }
}

public class SearchBox
{
    public string SearchText { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public SearchBox SearchBox { get; set; }
}
```

And your view:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MvcWebsite.Models.User.UserViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
{
....
}
```

And of course you should change the `@model` in your view code to comply with the changes:

```
@model MvcWebsite.Models.User.UserViewModel
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I am getting following error:


CS1061: 'PagedList.IPagedList<MvcBlog.Models.User.UserViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Categories' and no extension method 'Categories' accepting a first argument of type 'PagedList.IPagedList<MvcBlog.Models.User.UserViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


Line 42:             @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)